# NullPointerException in Avro ReflectDatumWriter

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, avro

I have a specific issue with Avro serialization of Java Objects. I have POJO's generated from xsd schemas which I am then trying to serialize using avro to place on a kafka topic. Some of the xmlElements are optional

A test message looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "message")
public class Testmessage {

  @XmlElement
  public String id;


  @XmlElement
  public String name;

  public Testmessage(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Testmessage() { }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Message{" +
        "id='" + id + '\'' +
        ", name=" + name +
        '}';
  }
}
```

And the method to serialize and place on the topic is:

```
public void sendMessage(Testmessage msg) throws Exception{

    DatumWriter<Testmessage> writer = new ReflectDatumWriter<Testmessage>(Testmessage.class); 
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(os, null);
    writer.write(msg, encoder);
    encoder.flush();
    os.close();
    KeyedMessage<String, byte[]> data = new KeyedMessage<String, byte[]>(TOPIC_NAME, os.toByteArray());

    producer.send(data);

}
```

When I send both fields all works as expected. If I null one of the fields or leave it out I get NPE's from the write.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: in Testmessage in string null of string in field id of    Testmessage
at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:145)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)
```

Any ideas? or point me in the right direction

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear that I ended managing to solve it myself after posting, a couple days of reading the internets later

```
    ReflectData reflectData = ReflectData.AllowNull.get();
    Schema schema = reflectData.getSchema(Testmessage.class);

    DatumWriter<Testmessage> writer = new ReflectDatumWriter<Testmessage>(schema);
```

Appears to allow the use of nulls quite happily.

On to my next error! which is

```
org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"record","name":"XMLGregorianCalendar","namespace":"javax.xml.datatype","fields":[]}]: 2014-10-22
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:604)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:151)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:71)
at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:143)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:114)
```

Comment: ReflectData.AllowNull.get() is the way to go.
Avro needs this extra flag to handle null values. I think this is so because the schema generated for such cases is much bigger than the objects without any null fields in the hierarchy.

Comment: Did you solve your "Not in union" error?  If so, how?

Comment: Yes as described below I converted to a string

Answer (score 1):

Avro does not support all the data-types.
Date and time support has been added very recently too (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-739)

So this might be due to XMLGregorianCalendar not being supported as a data-type in Avro.
Could you try using some other data-type (recommend using a String at first, before moving on to a more complex data type)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while testing my function in Junit, so I added also `ReflectData.AllowNull` to my function in the service then the test works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the values in the Java object that you're passing do comply with the Avro schema.

All the non-nullable fields should have a value, including List objects. If the field is of type List, initialize it with an empty list.

Stack trace for such an error would be similar to the following:

*java.lang.NullPointerException: in <class-name> in string null of string in field id of <class-name>
at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.**write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:145**)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.**writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:114)***

To find the exact field in the POJO which caused NullPointerException:

1. Add a debug point at the line where it throws the exception.
   According to the the above stack-trace it is the line 145 of
   ReflectDatumWriter.java.
2. Then navigate back the call stack (methods execution path) until you
   find the relevant field name. As in the picture, the name of the field
   is the value of the `Schema.Field` parameter passed to the `writeField`
   method.

[image]